# why dig to router is on DNS 53 port?

Tags: dns, ubuntu-12.10

192.168.1.1 is my router NetGear. It has 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 set as DNS. 
from windows:

```
nslookup google.com 192.168.1.1  // works OK
```

from ubuntu:

```
me@ubuntu:/etc/mail# dig @192.168.1.1 google.com +tcp
;; Connection to 192.168.1.1#53(192.168.1.1) for google.com failed: connection refused.
```

I think this shouldn't go on port 53, right? If yes, what can be the reason to `dig` translating my DNS query to asking NetGear on wrong port?

I cannot query 8.8.8.8:

```
dig @8.8.8.8 google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.2-P2 <<>> @8.8.8.8 google.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
root@ubuntuamd:/etc/mail# dig @8.8.8.8 google.com +tcp
```

however can with +tcp:

```
dig @8.8.8.8 google.com +tcp

; <<>> DiG 9.9.2-P2 <<>> @8.8.8.8 google.com +tcp
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 59432
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 16, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.     88  IN  A   46.28.247.93
google.com.     88  IN  A   46.28.247.119
//etc

;; Query time: 33 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Wed May  8 00:20:06 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 295
```

at the end this: here 127.0.1.1 (dnsmasq right?) responds:

```
 dig  google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.2-P2 <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 34747
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 16, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.     300 IN  A   208.117.224.29
//etc

;; Query time: 3 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1)
;; WHEN: Wed May  8 00:04:44 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 284
```

nm tool:

```
me@ubuntu:/etc/mail# nm-tool | tail -n 8   IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.1.3
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.1

    DNS:             192.168.1.1
```

Comment: Port 53 _is_ the DNS port. What makes you think it's wrong?

Comment: but for listening. My query shouldn't go on routers 53 but some random port, isn't it? if it is OK then why it is refused?

Comment: Your query should come from a random port (in a range) TO the designed server port of 53.

Comment: Is your Ubuntu machine even connected to the network correctly?

Comment: yes, I am on it currenntly

Comment: @restart.localhost.localdomain - for all we know your Ubuntu machine has iptables rules to block DNS requests to anything except trusted DNS. This is not uncommon - it can prevent some DNS highjacking requests, or bypassing corporate DNS.

Answer (score 6):

Port 53 is indeed the port that a DNS server listens on for requests.

However, by default it's UDP port 53, and TCP port 53 is not often used.

Your `dig` and `nslookup` commands use UDP by default, but in your `dig` command you specified to use TCP with `+tcp`, and since the router is only listening on UDP, the request fails.

To resolve the issue, query with UDP by removing `+tcp` from your `dig` command.

Comment: no, this doesn't work

Comment: Then provide the output.

Comment: dig @192.168.1.1 google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.2-P2 <<>> 192.168.1.1 google.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

Answer (score 1):

DNS runs on Port 53.

Port 53 is the [IANA assigned](http://www.iana.org/assignments/port-numbers) port for DNS.

`dig` does a DNS lookup. `nslookup` does a DNS lookup. Thus they both use Port 53.

As to your *real* question, which is:

> then why it is refused?

Well, that could be for any number of reasons. Maybe your Ubuntu computer is on a different network. Maybe its network cable is unplugged. Maybe you have firewall rules blocking outbound DNS except to some specific IP addresses.

Is there a specific problem you're trying to solve by doing this `dig` command?

Comment: yes, I cannot query 8.8.8.8 directly

Comment: please see the update

Comment: Try again without the `+tcp`

Comment: @DarthAndroid have you any idea why doesn't work without +tcp? on windows it works without +tcp

Comment: @restart.localhost.localdomain The default DNS port is 53 UDP. Sometimes, DNS servers simply aren't listening for a TCP connection because they're expecting UDP.

Comment: @DarthAndroid so do you think my settings are correct or is something wrong considering output listed in my question? why am I still able to search sites in browser? because secondly DNS queries after initial fail are translated into +tcp version?

Answer (score 1):

You should install bind and use `127.0.1.1`. This might help and resolve your problems.